# When/why to use the normal approximation inside a vertical strip?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution

The [Statistics book (Freedman, Piscani, Purves](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0393930432)) has a section about using the normal curve inside a vertical strip.  The introductory description is:

> Often, it is possible to use the normal approximation when working inside a vertical strip.  For this to be legitimate, the scatter diagram has to be football-shaped, with the dots thickly scattered in the center of the picture and facding off towards the edges.

They also provide a diagram showing this conceptually.  The diagram looks like this:

[image]

The question I have is: **When and why would you use this approach?**.

If I have understood correctly, I think you would use this approach if you are only provided with data about the subjects within the strip and need to calculate other values based on this data?

Comment: How would the normal approximation be used here? I understand the question and diagram, but am (sadly) ignorant of the purpose for this. If anyone has made use of this technique, please at least add an explanatory comment.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to know, for example, the mean and std. dev. of weight for people with heights between 1.8 and 2 meters (or, more broadly, for heights broken up into discrete intervals), that would be one application.  If you wanted to know what percentile of the population a particular individual in a particular height grouping fell into, the Normal approximation would come in handy there.

Comment: As the book proceeds to explain in the next several chapters, this is one basis to justify ordinary least squares regression.  For "when and why," then, you can consult (literally) millions of scientific and practical applications--including dozens described in the text itself.